# Can access _id of a references object but not the object directly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

`User has_many :organizations`

```
create_table "organizations", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "founder_id"
```

I can assign founder_id, but not access Founder (method missing).

```
class CreateOrganizations < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table :organizations do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.belongs_to :founder, :class_name => "User"
```

What do I need to change so I can access the founder (a User) attr on an Oranization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method belongs_to should be called on Organization class, like this:

```
class Organization
  belongs_to :founder, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

And in migration:

```
create_table :organizations do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.integer :founder_id
end
```

Comment: Oh, so I had those backwards.. trying.

Comment: Hm.. now this is an issue, with rails_admin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929802/no-such-column-with-a