# No such column with a belongs_to class_name relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: organizations.user_id: SELECT "organizations".* FROM "organizations"  WHERE "organizations"."user_id" = 2`

I have setup my models like this:

User:

`User has_many :organizations`

Organization:

```
attr_accessible :name, :founder, :founder_id
belongs_to :founder, :class_name => 'User'
```

Schema:

```
create_table "organizations", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.integer  "founder_id"
```

When I go to edit a user in rails-admin, I get this message:

```
`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: organizations.user_id: SELECT "organizations".* FROM "organizations"  WHERE "organizations"."user_id" = 2`
```

I want to access Founder on Organization, where a Founder is a User.
It looks like `rails_admin` looks for the user_id when it should be looking for a Founder.

Previous q:
[Can access _id of a references object but not the object directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928190/can-access-id-of-a-references-object-but-not-the-object-directly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify which column to use when retrieving organizations from User, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations, foreign_key: :founder_id

  #...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Organization model is belong to User, so rails will automatic use the User's lowercase class name +_id(user_id) as foreign_key.
Since your Organization model doesn't have the user_id but the founder_id, you need to explicit specify the founder_id as foreign_key.